# How do I manually resolve conflicts and mark them as resolve when using TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

Coming from the SVN world this was dead easy:
1) do the merge and get a conflict. SVN gives you the conflicting files in the working copy.
2) resolve them any way you need to (using any external tool if required).
3) "svn resolved" to mark the conflict as resolved.
4) check in (or carry on working, etc).

Now with TFS and Visual Studio (2010), the only options we seem to have are: -
-> Merge in the TFS merge tool (text files only).
-> For non text files, take the source branch file (overwrite target branch file) or keep the target branch file (ignore the source branch file).

I need to be able to resolve conflicts for some of my file types using external tools (E.g. Erwin) and then mark the conflict as resolved.

I've tried resolving the conflict, putting the new file into the target branch filesystem workspace (i.e. the working copy) and using "tf resolve /auto:DeleteConflict". That didn't help. The local resolved/consolidated file was completely ignored when I finally checked in the merge.

Surely TFS/VS can do this!

Any help would really be appreciated!!

Thanks.

Comment: As a supplement to tbergstedt's answer [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmanning/archive/2006/02/20/diff-merge-configuration-in-team-foundation-common-command-and-argument-values.aspx) has a comprehensive breakdown of how to call out from TFS to 3rd party merge tools. If you can call ERwin from the command line, you will be able to invoke it from TFS

Comment: Thanks for that lead but alas ERwin doesn't seem to support any command line arguments. The other tool that I need to use certainly doesn't. Any other ideas, please!?

Answer (score 3):

You can set up specific rules for Compare and Merge in Visual Studio. It is located under **Tools->Options->Source Control->Visual Studio Team Foundation Server**. Choose **Configure User Tools...**, and from there you can select any external tool to use for your operations. 
You can use file filters to define any number of rules and add here for Operation "Merge" any custom tool:
[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: The first tool I've tried to set up (ERwin) doesn't work with this. I'm certain the other tool I also need to use won't work with this mechanism either.

Comment: Is there a way of manually resolving the conflict as in SVN, or is the ONLY way of resolving a conflict through the merge conflict resolution dialogue (or later on the "Resume Conflict Resolution")?!

Comment: ERwin doesn't accept command line arguments! Any other way to get this working?

Comment: In that case, I can see two alternatives: 1) If ERwin has some kind of API you could build your own interface to use for merging. 2) The more manual way would be to perform the merge, pause at the resolving conflict stage, resolve the necessary conflicts in ERwin and overwrite the targets, back in VS resolve every (ERwin) conflict with `take target version`. You can check the results afterwards before checking anything in. A bit of a hassle, but you can't blame TFS for not being able to handle a program that only accepts GUI interface...

Comment: I've definately already tried "Take Target Version" but it ignored the file that I put in the target branch local workspace and just accepted the server version! That only really leaves the "/auto:AcceptMerge" option from the answer below (which I'm still to try). If that's no longer valid in TFS/VS2010 then I've had it. I can blame TFS completely actually! Text, text, text. What about no text? Have they ready the SVN manual!? ;p

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the content that you want on disk (after manually using your merge tool) instead of running "tf resolve /auto:DeleteConflict", run "tf resolve /auto:AcceptMerge".  This tells TFS to accept the content that is on disk as the resolution of the merge.

Comment: Really!? That's not documented in the docs I've seen. Where did you find that one? I'll try it out.

Comment: Actually, it is listed on the Visual Studio 2005 pages on MSDN, but not the 2010 pages. I'm using 2010. Will let you know if this works or not.

Comment: Right, this ("/auto:AcceptMerge") has been tried now. It didn't work! This was the error message:

Binary files cannot be merged unless an encoding override is specified.

Then a message about the source and target both having changes. I.e. a conflict (!!).

Any ideas people?!

Comment: Also tried adding ".erwin" to the list of file types that are merge-able at the project collection level. That doesn't help either.